# cocos2d rotating sprite collision detection

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I got 2 sprites, ball and arrow.
the arrow is not moving.
the ball is rotating on it's anchor point.

```
id rotate = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:.5 angle: 360];
```

I want to detect collision when the ball reaches to arrow.
Tried CGRectIntersectsRect but it does not detect collision. 
Any help?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want this answer, but I would use Box2D or Chipmunk and use the Vertex Helper application to specify vertices.

Comment: i am trying to use Box2D. After i set anchorpoint (-1,-1) to Sprite, the sprite and groundbody are not overlapped each other anymore. groundbody remains rotating at original point while the sprite is rotating at (-1,-1) position. so the collision is detecting where groundbody located. :(

Comment: In that case I would try out what xuanweng said to do.

Answer (score 0):

use circle-circle collision method.. here is the method..

```
-(float)asbs:(CGPoint)_arrowPos ballPos:(CGPoint)_ballPos
{
    float x = _arrowPos.x-_ballPos.x;
    float y = _arrowPos.y-_ballPos.y;
    float xy = x*x+y*y;

return xy;
}

if([self asbs:arrow.position ballPos:ball.position]<=size)
{
//collision
}
```

note that size = ball radius + arrow radius * ball radius + arrow radius

the method above is using a(square) + b(square) = c(square) to check distance between two points..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. the arrow is not a circle. wonder why the size become size = ball radius + arrow radius * ball radius + arrow radius

Comment: then change to a detection radius or detection point?? cos we are comparing the squared points..

Comment: Hi, I set the ball position - "ball.position = CGPointMake(85,85);." While rotating, ball position is changed but when i print in console, "NSLog(@"ball position %f", ball.position.x);" it cannot detect the current location. printed out 85 constantly.

Comment: hmm.. is the ball sprite attached to a layer?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert the ball to world space in an update method then call that rather than the balls position. If it is in a parent layer is position will always be static in respect to its parent.